# Is it faster to refer to jQuery objects (mostly DOM objects) by the variable name only, or by $?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

To put it simply:

Is this:

```
var x = $('#selector-id');
x.slideDown();
```

Faster than:

```
var x = $('#selector-id');
$(x).slideDown();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second version clones the jQuery object...for no reason really, so yes the first is both faster and more efficient (less wasteful).

Comment: Sorry I never accepted your answer. I sort of forgot that I even asked anything here! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

The second example doesn't make sense, as `x` is already a jQuery object.

It would make more sense if you did:

```
var selector_string = '#selector-id';
$(selector_string).slideDown();
```

but that would definitely be slower than the first option as you'll be accessing the DOM and making a new jQuery object every time you use it.

Comment: I wouldn't call `getElementById()` "traversing the DOM", but yes it is wasteful :)

Comment: That's true, but I've seen people do the second one a lot so I was just wondering. I thought the first one was more efficient too, thanks for the replies!

Comment: @Nick - in that case I guess not, but I'm thinking of the more general case of `var x = someKindOfSelectorAsAString;`

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it is faster because it makes one less function call. Practically you would never write the second because x is already a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

remember dom acessing just slowdowns your javascript,  more you access the DOM more less efficient it becomes.

below are few examples

```
var _elm= jQuery('.myElement');
_elm.DoThis();
_elm.DoThat();
```

above 2 will be faster than  below written 2

```
jQuery('.myElement').DoThis();
jQuery('.myElement').DoThat();
```

// you may use firebug's profiler to test this.